# Equal sides of an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Problem: find an index N where the sum of the integers to the left of N is equal to the sum of the integers to the right of N. If there is no index that would make this happen, return -1.

My solution

```js
function findEvenIndex(arr) {
  var sum = i => i.reduce((a, b) => a + b),
    l = arr.length;

  for (let j = 0; j <= l; j++) {
    if (sum(arr.slice(0, j - 1)) === sum(arr.slice(j, l))) {
      return j
    } else {
      continue;
    }
  }
  return -1

}
```

When I run `findEvenIndex([1,2,3,4,3,2,1])`, it doesn't return anything. Where is the error that prevents 3 from being returned in the case of this example?

I've set the for loop procedure as follows to see what's going on

```
  for(let j = 0; j <= arr.length; j++){
    var left = arr.slice(0, j-1), right = arr.slice(j)
    console.log(left, right)
  } 
/* returns 
[1] [3,4,3,2,1] 
[1,2] [4,3,2,1] 
[1,2,3] [3,2,1]
as expected
*/
```

However, when try to console.log the sum of these arrays:

```
function sum(i){ return i.reduce((a, b) => a+b)} 
    
    var l = arr.length;
  
  for(let j = 0; j <= l; j++){
    var left = arr.slice(0, j-1), right = arr.slice(j)
    console.log(sum(left), sum(right))
  }
```

Using the snippet above, findEvenIndex([1,2,3,4,3,2,1]) returns "15 16"?

Comment: Could you indent properly and explain what you are struggling with ? What's not ok with your solution ?

Comment: What is not correct about your solution? What is your problem? What is a sample dataset[s] that give you a problem?

Comment: The error in your developer console should tell you want it the problem. Your code is not set up right to produce sub arrays. Simple console.log() lines would shed light into what you are doing. `for (let j = 0; j <= l; j++) { console.log(arr.slice(0, j - 1), arr.slice(j, l));`

Comment: I always enjoy when question is closed as I am writing up an answer.... Guess I can not show OP how to properly loop over the array and get the sub arrays.

Comment: How your slice code should look:
`var arr = [0,1,2,3,4,5];
for (let j = 1; j < arr.length; j++) {
  var arrLeft = arr.slice(0,j);
  var arrRight = arr.slice(j);
  console.log(arrLeft, arrRight)
}`

Answer (score -1):

your for loop is going all the way to `l` where it should stop at `l-1`

---

This isn't needed:

```
} else {
  continue;
}
```

---

performance wise, you don't need to compute so many stuff each time.

An alternative would be to progressively sum elements before your pivot and check if it's equal to half of (sum of all elements minus pivot value)

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the usage of reduce here..... Your advice is wrong.

Comment: oh right, I thought init value was required for some reason

Comment: a closing parenthesis would probably help

Comment: HUH? I think you need to look again. And you did not actually figure out the cause of the issue.