# Splitting array into equal halves

Tags: javascript, arrays

Problem: find an index N where the sum of the integers to the left of N is equal to the sum of the integers to the right of N. If there is no index that would make this happen, return -1.

My solution

```js
function findEvenIndex(arr) {
  var sum = i => i.reduce((a, b) => a + b),
    l = arr.length;

  for (let j = 0; j <= l; j++) {
    if (sum(arr.slice(0, j - 1)) === sum(arr.slice(j, l))) {
      return j
    } else {
      continue;
    }
  }
  return -1

}
console.log(
  findEvenIndex([1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 1])
)
```

When I run this on say findEvenIndex([1,2,3,4,3,2,1]), It doesn't return anything? Where is the error that prevents 3 from being returned in the case of this example?

I've set the for loop procedure as follows to see what's going on

```
  for(let j = 0; j <= arr.length; j++){
    var left = arr.slice(0, j-1), right = arr.slice(j)
    console.log(left, right)
  } 
/* returns 
[1] [3,4,3,2,1] 
[1,2] [4,3,2,1] 
[1,2,3] [3,2,1]
as expected
*/
```

However, when try to console.log the sum of these arrays:

```
function sum(i){ return i.reduce((a, b) => a+b)} 
    
    var l = arr.length;
  
  for(let j = 0; j <= l; j++){
    var left = arr.slice(0, j-1), right = arr.slice(j)
    console.log(sum(left), sum(right))
  }
```

Using the snippet above, findEvenIndex([1,2,3,4,3,2,1]) returns "15 16"?

Comment: I made you a snippet. [edit] and create [mcve] from your code

Comment: _"Where is the error"_ - go check the browser console (or the console in the snippet above), it will tell you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Equal sides of an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69978016/equal-sides-of-an-array)

Answer (score 1):

The main issue with your code is that calling `sum([])` throws an error (which you will find in the console during debugging):

> Reduce of empty array with no initial value

The `reduce` method does not know what to return if your array doesn't have any values. You solve it by passing the initial value as a second argument to `.reduce`:

```js
const add = (a, b) => a + b;

[1, 2, 3].reduce(add); // add(add(1, 2), 3)
[1, 2].reduce(add);    // add(1, 2)
[1].reduce(add);       // 1
[].reduce(add);        // ERROR: Reduce of empty array 
                       //        with no initial value

[1, 2].reduce(add, 0); // add(add(0, 1), 2)
[1].reduce(add, 0);    // add(0, 1)
[].reduce(add, 0);     // 0
```

Once you fix that, it's easier to debug the rest of the code.

### Fixing it

Here's an example that I think does what it should do:

```js
function findEvenIndex(arr) {
  //                    Add a seed value --v
  var sum = i => i.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0),
      l = arr.length;

  for (let j = 0; j <= l; j++) {
    const left = arr.slice(0, j);
    const right = arr.slice(j + 1);
    const leftSum = sum(left);
    const rightSum = sum(right);
    
    console.log(
      { left, right, leftSum, rightSum }
    );
    
    if (leftSum === rightSum) {
      return j
    }
  }
  return -1
}

console.log(
  findEvenIndex([1]), // 0
  findEvenIndex([1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 1]), // 3
  findEvenIndex([10, 0, 5, 5]), // 1
  findEvenIndex([3, 2, 1]) // -1
)
```

### Another approach

Note that looping over all elements of the array for every index is quite expensive! A more efficient approach would be:

- Take the sum of the source array, store it as `rightSum`
- Define `leftSum` as 0
- Look at the integer value at index 0 and *subtract* it from `rightSum`
- If `leftSum === rightSum`, return `0`
- Else, add value to `leftSum` and increment index
- Once you've reached the final index, return `-1`

```js
const findEvenIndex = (arr) => {
  let leftSum = 0;
  let rightSum = arr
    .reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
  
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i += 1) {
    const n = arr[i];
    rightSum -= n;
    
    if (leftSum === rightSum) return i;
    leftSum += n;
  }

  return -1;
}

console.log(
  findEvenIndex([1]), // 0
  findEvenIndex([1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 1]), // 3
  findEvenIndex([10, 0, 5, 5]), // 1
  findEvenIndex([3, 2, 1]) // -1
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the index like following using reduce(). Your implementation regarding reduce() is not correct.

```js
function findEvenIndex(arr)
{
  for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    let leftSum = arr.slice(0, i).reduce((accumulator, current) => accumulator + current, 0);
    let rightSum = arr.slice(i + 1).reduce((accumulator, current) => accumulator + current, 0);
    if (leftSum === rightSum) {
      return i;
    }
  }
  return -1;
}
console.log(
  findEvenIndex([1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 1])
)
```

Please check following blog to find out how Array **reduce()** work

```
https://www.javascripttutorial.net/javascript-array-reduce/
```

Answer (score 0):

Upon finishing my solution, I noticed that it's effectively the same as @Abu's answer above. The idea is to brute force the way through the array, comparing the two halves as you go.

```
/* 
    Find an index N where the sum of the integers to the left of N is equal to the sum of the integers to the right of N. If there is no index that would make this happen, return -1
*/

const array = [10, 90, 10, 1, 10, 90, 10];

// incrementTotal :: (Number t, Number n) -> t
incrementTotal = (total, number) => total + number;

// indexIsEqual :: (Array a, Number c) -> Boolean
function indexIsEqual(array, count) {
    let chunkL = array.slice(0, count-1);
    let chunkR = array.slice(count , );

    return chunkL.reduce(incrementTotal) === chunkR.reduce(incrementTotal); 
}

// findEvenIndex :: (Array a) -> (a[x] || -1)
function findEvenIndex(array) {
    for (let count = 2; count < array.length; count++) {
        if (indexIsEqual(array, count)) {
            return array[count-1];
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

console.log(findEvenIndex(array));
```